# variable selection with missing values

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset with count dependent variables such as `greetings` and ordinal independent variables like `education` and `social` etc., but `education` has some zero values (which are represented by `NA`). Now I'm doing a variable selection with `glmer`. my question is, is it necessary to make a new data set without the `NA`s (which means with fewer observations for the whole dataset) when I compare the models with and without `education`? because the AIC values are different from the old and new dataset.

old dataset with `education`

```
model1 <- glmer(greetings ~ education + socialrole + countedmembers + topic +
                 offset(log(words)) + (1|people), family=negative.binomial(1), 
            data=dat.old)####AIC 1119.0
```

without `education`

```
model2 <- glmer(greetings ~ socialrole + countedmembers + topic +
                 offset(log(words)) + (1|people), family=negative.binomial(1), 
            data=dat.old)####AIC 1182.0
```

new dataset with `education`:

```
model3 <- glmer(greetings ~ education + socialrole + countedmembers + topic +
                 offset(log(words)) + (1|people), family=negative.binomial(1), 
            data=dat.new)###AIC 1119.0
```

without `education`:

```
model4 <- glmer(greetings ~ socialrole + countedmembers + topic +
                 offset(log(words)) + (1|people), family=negative.binomial(1), 
            data=dat.new)###AIC 1117.3
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pretty much.  This isn't really a mixed-model-specific question.  Because AIC (along with other likelihood-based approaches) is only meaningful when compared across different models fitted to the same data set, you can really only do model selection across equivalent data sets.  You have some hard choices to make:

- suck it up and reduce your data set to complete cases only
- restrict your set of candidate predictors to those without too many missing data, or with missing data patterns similar to other predictors (then see #1)
- use some method of [imputation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_%28statistics%29) to fill in missing values (this is unfortunately not simple and easy)

I would recommend Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies* book for an introduction to imputation, exploring patterns of missingness, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot! but there are only a few NAs just in that two variables. is it better to make two new data set for them when I need the two for regression (when not then still work with the whole data set) or to reduce the data set for all variables?

Comment: hard to say.  it depends how important the two variables you would have to drop are, relative to how much information you would lose from discarding the cases with missing values.